# UTF8 encoding to write with accents

Tags: accents

I try to write with accents (spanish) but the pdf doesn't show any accented character. 
Here's my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt, spanish]{report}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

On the one hand if select 'UTF8 encoding' the .tex doesn't compile. On the other hand, if I select, for example, 'latin1 encoding' the .tex does compile, but there are no accentuated characters in the pdf.

I also have some .tex files from years ago which compiled and wrote accents but not now.

Comment: Are you actually saving the file in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, if I select 'Document' -> 'Character Encoding' -> 'UTF8' with this preamble doesn't compile. If I select another 'Latin1' does compile but without showing accentuated characters

Comment: Exactly which editor are you using? Might be useful to know which OS you are using as well (some OSes has tools we can use to check files). It sounds like the file is actually being saved as latin1 by default. Most editors cannot change the chosen encoding (though some can)

Comment: The saved file encoding and the encoding declared in the `inputenc` option have to match you can use either encoding (or other encodings) as long as the option matches the actual encoding.

Comment: I've already checked the actual encoding with the command 'file -bi filename.tex' and the result is UTF8. I actually removed the whole texlive and reinstalled but the problem remains..

Comment: I'm sure it's a problem from the compiler, because I've used some fast compiling in the text editor and the accentuated characters ara shown

Comment: Soyou have `cm-super` or `lmodern` installed?

Comment: i've tried with the \usepackage{lmodern} too, but doesn't work

Comment: if you want us to help you need to show something that goes wrong, complete your example to a complete 5 or 6 line document including accented characters and then also post the full log file as a code section in the question (`{}` button in the editor) and then people can reproduce.